# Jquery compatibility issue with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

The "edit" and "delete" button don't show in IE, but they shows correctly in FF and Chrome. I think the Jquery code is not compatible with IE. So anyone can help me to figure out a way that works on all browsers?

```
    <form method="get" id="screening-form">
      <?php echo $vs ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php echo $next_action; ?>" />

      <?php echo $widget->render('screeningid') ?>

      <br />
      <div id="submitInputs">
        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
      </div>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#screeningid_dialog_button").change(function() {
          if($(this).data("hidden")) {
            $("#submitInputs").show();
          } else {
            $("#submitInputs").hide();
          }
        }).change();
      });
    </script>
```

[image: search]
[image: result]
[image: showing "edit" and "delete" button]

Comment: Why do you have `.change()` at the end of the `change` event callback?

Comment: What is `#screeningid_dialog_button` ?

Comment: are you getting a javascript error in IE?   jQuery IS compatible with IE, so it's got to be something else.

Comment: @PeeHaa. To trigger the change event directly.

Comment: Without seeing your markup its hard to say, but my guess is that #screeningid_dialog_button is an HTML element that doesn't respond to the `change` event. Depending on the type of element you might need to replace this with `click`, `keyup` or some other event type.

Comment: @庆峰 扈: why do you do that? Can't you just use CSS to hide it initially?

Comment: @PeeHaa. I don't do anything, 庆峰 扈 is. But you're right when it comes to simply show/hide. When you're change event handler does more, it is sometimes necessary to trigger the event.

Comment: @DidierG.: who said you did anything? What are you talking about? ;-)

Comment: I attached the images about the steps to get to the issue "Edit" and "Delete" button. I am not the one who wrote the code, I just need to fix it

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why where is the id screeningid_dialog_button defined. It is not defined in the file that code located